# Partitioning strategy : Full partitioning vs aligned partitioning in Sql Server (tuning options in database engine tuning advisor)

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning, database-tuning-advisor

In Database engine tuning advisor, there is an option of Partitioning strategy:
Full partitioning vs aligned partitioning.

What is meant by full partitioning and aligned partitioning and what are its pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that this topic is not relevant anymore, but anyway.
To someone, who interested in it, check that link https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/05/14/database-engine-tuning-advisordta-in-sql-server/

And what I found here

> **Full partitioning**
> You can select this option if you want Partitioning suggestions. You can
> find details about the Partition concept in the article “How To Create
> Partition On SQL Server“.

> **Aligned partitioning**
> You should select this option if you want indexes to be aligned according
> to the partition when Partition is recommended. For information about the
> details of the Align process, please read to the article named “Can Not   > Switch The Partition On SQL Server“.